# Non-diagonalizability of the adjacency matrix of a directed graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrices

Let $G$ be a directed graph with no multiple edges or  loops and let $P_i$ be its vertices. Let  $A$ be the corresponding adjacency matrix of $G$, i.e. $a_{i,j}=1$ if and only if there is a directed edge from $P_i$ to $P_j$, ($a_{i,j}=0$ otherwise). Suppose that there is  a path in $G$ that is not included in any cycle. Can we conclude that $A$ is not diagonalizable (over the field of reals)?

Comment: Do you mean to assume that the graph is weakly connected? If not, then consider, for a counterexample, a graph $G$ with four states $A,B,C,D$, with three edges: a $2$-cycle $A \to B \to A$ and a lone edge $C \to D$. If the graph is weakly connected then I think it's probably true. (I use the convention that $A$ for the $G$ I described has $3$ entries equal to $1$ and $13$ entries equal to $0$.)

Comment: @SophieMacDonald, your graph has a nilpotent block so isn't diagonalizable. So it isn't a counterexample. The adjacency matrix should be diagonalizable iff this is the case for each weak component

Comment: By a cycle, do you mean an oriented cycle?

Comment: In fact the question for the converse  is more suited if diagonalisation is over $\mathbb{C}$. As: 'Can we conclude that A is not diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$)? What about the converse?'

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე
A cycle or simple circuit is a circuit in which only the first and last vertices are equal

Comment: My example does not have multiple edges as a digraph.  In any event you can do a similar idea with any strongly connected graph with diagonalizable adjacency matrix

Comment: Related question from same user on m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697183/examples-of-a-special-kind-of-directed-graphs

Comment: Final suggestion to OP. Please put or add your other question on mathstack here (the one with  type I - it is the converse-) and check the edit i have sent. You need to add every vertix of the path does not belong to a directed cycle...

Comment: All these edits are a bit confusing.  I am not longer sure if it is the OP or other who object to complex diagonalization

Comment: The OP seems to do operator algebras and is probably interested in Cuntz-Kreiger algebras.  If complex eigenvalues are ok, I can easily write down an example without 2-cycles that is diagonalizable and has an edge outside a cycle.  If I need real eigenvalues, its a bit trickier to find diagonalizable examples without 2-cycles.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg, the vertices (all) of this path are not in a directed cycle (loop)... (i proposed the edits :)

Comment: @ToniMhax, I don't think it is a good idea to change the question to makes answers no longer an answer.  One can also do variation where I replace the single vertex by a different digraph.  But the 2-cycle issue is the bigger concern.

Comment: I think the question doesn't want the whole path contained in a cycle.  If you have a path with no vertex belonging to a cycle, then it is obviously non diagonalizable because you have a weak component that is acyclic.

Comment: OP, am I correct you are ok with the path containing vertices in a cycle but just not the whole path included in the cycle

Comment: @ToniMhax, I rejected your edit and returned to the OP's original wording.  If no vertex of a path belongs to a cycle, then you have a weak component that is an acyclic digraph and this gives a block direct sum of a nilpotent matrix with something else and so is obviously not diagonalizable.  The OP's original formulation is a more interesting question but I would still like to know if 2-cycles are ok before working hard to remove the 2-cycle

Comment: Yes no issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question is no.  Consider the digraph with vertices $1,2,3$ and a directed edge from $1$ to $2$ and from $2$ to $1$ and both $1$ and $2$ have directed edges to $3$.  Then the adjacency matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 & 1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has three distinct eigenvalues $0,1,-1$.

**Added.**
Since there seems to be some quibbling about whether 2-cycles are legitimate or not and what the field should be, let me point out that the basic idea of this construction lets you build counterexamples fairly freely.  Let $\Gamma_0$ be any digraph with nonsingular diagonalizable adjacency matrix $A_0$ over the reals.    Now adjoin a new vertex $\ast$ and  connect all the vertices of $\Gamma_0$ to $\ast$ by a directed edge to get $\Gamma$.   Then the adjacency matrix  $A$ of $\Gamma$ is
$\begin{bmatrix} A_0 & \mathbf 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $\mathbf 1$ is a column of ones.  If $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ is a basis of eigenvectors for $A_0$,  then $(v_1,0),\ldots, (v_n,0)$ is a linearly independent set of eigenvectors of $A$ with the same eigenvalues, hence none of these vectors have eigenvalue $0$.  Since $0$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A$, adjoining to this collection an eigenvector for $0$ gives a basis of eigenvectors for $A$ and so $A$ is diagonalizable.  So if you work over $\mathbb C$ you can choose $\Gamma_0$ a directed cycle. If you allow a $2$-cycle this works over $\mathbb R$.  Otherwise you need $2$-cycle and loop free digraphs with nonsingular adjacency matrix diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.  I can try to cook one up later if $2$-cycles are objectionable.

Comment: Actually, I only need one edge from either 1 or 2 to 3, but oh well this looks nicer when you draw it.

Comment: I guess no multiple edges are allowed (1->2->1). I think the answer to the direct  question (i edit it) is yes, A is not diagonalisable in this case.

Comment: @ToniMhax Forbidding 2-cycles does not save it, there is the same kind of counterexample with a 3-cycle: 4 vertices, cycle $1\to2\to3\to1$ and three more edges $k\to4$, $k=1,2,3$. The adjacency matrix is conjugable to the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $0,1,\omega,\omega^2$, where $\omega$ is the third root of unity.

Comment: (In fact similar "$n$-wheel" counterexamples exist for all $n$)

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I edited the condition, the vertices of say a certain path should not be in a (direct loop) cycle (here the k are in a cycle).

Comment: @ToniMhax For what it's worth, in a directed graph, $1\to 2$ and $2\to 1$ are usually considered to be distinct edges, so the presence of both of them is usually not considered to be a "multiple edge." For a multiple edge, you would need something like multiple instances of the directed edge $1\to 2$. If you want to exclude the presence of both $1\to 2$ and $2\to 1$ then you might say something like, "the underlying undirected graph has no multiple edges."

Comment: I think if you do not allow 2-cycles and you require real eigenvalues you get very few diagonalizable adjacency matrices.  Strongly connected digraphs tends to have complex eigenvalues due to Perron-Frobenius while non-strongly connected ones tend to not be diagonalizable unless you arrange things carefully as I did.

Comment: I proposed this edit thanks.